# Qt creator: paintEvent of Qwidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have some problems. Hope anyone can help me.
I have a Qwidget1 and Qwidget2. Qwidget1 have a widget that promote to Qwidget2. Both Qwidget1 and Qwidget2 have paintEvent. I have writed "qDebug()<< "Update"; " in paint event of Qwidget1. When I run project, I see a word "Update" has been printed a lot of times. So why Qwidget1 execute paint event a lot of times. How can I fix it, just execute paint event when show Qwidget1 at the first time and when I call update.

Comment: Nothing's broken here.

Comment: Please tell me the reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. Your code works like it should. From Qt documentation:

> A paint event is a request to repaint all or part of a widget. It can
>   happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> repaint() or update() was invoked,
>
> the widget was obscured and has now been uncovered,
>
> or many other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

There can be any number of situations when a window or its part becomes invalidated and has to be repainted. Such situations include, but are not limited to:

- window size change (including minimizing / maximizing / restoring the window);
- mouse pointer passing over a widget - it may or may not trigger repaint;
- other window moving over the window in question.

When it happens, Windows will send the `WM_PAINT` message to the application. You could check whether or not the number of `WM_PAINT`  messages received matches the number of `paintEvent` calls, but I doubt Qt adds any significant overhead.

Comment: no change window size, no mouse pointer passing over a widget and no other window moving over the window. When I delete paint event of Qwidget2, I see paint event of Qwidget1 only execute one time.